# Why do you need to pass in an SPField Collection?

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint

When i am creating SPFields the constructor states that you must pass in a collection of fields.

Can anyone enlighten me on why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The constructor wants some contextual information about which collection of fields it will be added to. You shouldn't create new fields this way, though. Instead, use `SPFieldCollection.Add()` - which will construct the object *and* add it to the appropriate collection.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I am doing it this way so I construct a loop to check that the fields don't already exist otherwise i would have to put a check around every field that I add to the collection otherwise there is the possibility that duplications will occur so i believe. Have you got any other ways of doing this i am fairly new to sharepoint

Comment: You can use `SPFieldCollection.ContainsField()` to do your duplicate check.